# ¿Cómo editar el contenido de un elemento html al hacer click?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Amigos, estoy tratando de editar el contenido de un elemento HTML al hacer click y cargar el contenido dentro de un modal para poder ser modificado.

He logrado realizar dicha tarea pero se me presentó el siguiente problema:

Al dar click al elemento, si en la página se encuentran elementos similares el contenido que toma para cargar y ser modificado es el del primer elemento en la página. He tratado de darle solución agregando id y clases al momento de dar click pero sin resultado.
Si alguien tiene una idea mejor me seria de gran ayuda.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="es">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZCSftd1LZCfmhktB" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <title>Hello, world!</title>

    <style>
        .block_editable{
            background-color:red;
            padding: 8px;
        }

        div:hover{
            border: 1px solid blue;
        }
        p:hover{
            border: 1px solid red;
        }
        h1,h2,h3,h4.h5,h6:hover{
            border: 1px solid green;    
        }
    </style>
  </head>
  <!-- <body onmousedown="elemento(event);"> -->
  <body onmousedown="elemento2(event);">      
    {% raw %}

    <div>
        <h1>demo</h1>
    </div>
    <div>
        <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Eveniet, perspiciatis. Deserunt delectus, cupiditate, cumque, molestiae nesciunt sequi repellat voluptatibus cum dignissimos neque suscipit sunt quaerat perferendis rerum fugiat, eum eaque.
        </p>
        <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nobis minima ea, neque, laudantium dolor eveniet odit? Eos possimus consequatur, facere voluptatem eligendi quibusdam aspernatur sed, expedita, voluptas, suscipit at hic!
        </p>
        <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ullam et adipisci rerum magni nisi repudiandae unde laborum quis, perferendis aliquam nesciunt, veritatis, dolorem aliquid vero tempore in inventore facilis minus?
        </p>
    </div>

    <!-- Button trigger modal -->
    <button type="button" id="carga" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
      Launch demo modal
    </button>

    <!-- Modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
      <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
              <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            <div class="input-group">
              <div class="input-group-prepend">
                <span class="input-group-text">1</span>
              </div>
              <textarea id="edit_code" class="form-control" aria-label="With textarea"></textarea>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            <button id="save" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    {% endraw %}
    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-smHYKdLADwkXOn1EmN1qk/HfnUcbVRZyYmZ4qpPea6sjB/pTJ0euyQp0Mk8ck+5T" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <script>


        function elemento2(e){
            if (e.srcElement){

                obj.tag = e.srcElement.localName;     

                //Agrega id y clase a elmento seleccionado
                $(obj.tag).attr('id','editar')
                $(obj.tag).attr('class','editar')

                var cnt_tag = $("#editar.editar").html()

                $(obj.tag).attr('data-toggle','modal')
                $(obj.tag).attr('data-target', '#exampleModal')


                var cnt_tag2 = $('#edit_code').html(cnt_tag)


                $("#save").click(function(){

                    $("#editar.editar").html(cnt_tag2)
                    //remover id y classe del elememto seleccionado 

                    $("#editar.editar").removeClass('editar')
                    $("#editar.editar").attr('id', 'editado')

                    console.log("test ")

                })

                console.log(cnt_tag)


            }else if (e.target){
                tag = e.target.tagName; // Internet explorer
            }
        }


    </script>
  </body>  
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

### [Contenido editable (HTML5)](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Atributos_Globales/contenteditable)

El nuevo estándar **Html5** permite crear contenido editable colocando el atributo para tal efecto `contentEditable="true"` en el elemento que quieres sea editable.

en el siguiente ejemplo te muestro como hacerlo:

```html
<div style="background-color:#FFCCCC">
  <h3>Contenido NO Editable</h3>
  este contenido está dentro de un Elemento <b>NO! editable</b>
</div>

<div style="background-color:#CCFFCC" contentEditable="true">
  <h3>Contenido Editable</h3>
  este contenido está dentro de un Elemento <b>editable</b><br>
  (Haz clic aqui para editar el contenido)
</div>
```

Ten en cuenta que solo funciona en exploradores que soporten el estándar HTML5.

Espero esto te ayude!! ;))...

Answer (score 0):

Los modales son una especie destinada a la extinción. Surgieron en el siglo pasado y hoy son considerados como un elemento que conduce a una mala experiencia de usuario.

En el caso que planteas, podrías tener perfectamente un `TextArea` (o cualquier otro elemento editable), el cual puedes modificar a tu gusto.

Esa apertura de ventanas (modales) que saltaban a nuestra vista, que nos sorprendían y hasta nos resultaban agradables, hoy día ya no lo son tanto.

En el ejemplo siguiente, verás que puedes seguir en tiempo real las modificaciones de tu `TextArea`. Si esto no es necesario puedes obviar esa primera función, no hay por qué cargar el programa de funciones innecesarias, pero la he escrito como demostración.

También verás que, al clic de un botón, podrás recuperar el contenido final de tu `TextArea`. Si lo que interesa es recuperar el contenido final, esto sería lo más óptimo.

Yo preferiría esto a un modal, por lo que he dicho antes y porque es el que camino a seguir: integrar lo más posible en una misma interfaz gráfica dinámica. Abrir un modal implicaría añadir al menos dos o tres acciones suplementarias.

```js
var txaEditable = document.getElementById("txaEditable");
var btnLeer = document.getElementById("btnLeer");

/*Escuchando cambios en tiempo real si fuera necesario*/
txaEditable.onkeyup = function() {
  console.log(this.value);
};

/*Obtener el contenido final desde otro evento*/
btnLeer.onclick = function() {
  console.log("El elemento " + txaEditable.id + " tiene el valor:\n" + txaEditable.value);
};
```

```html
<textarea id="txaEditable" name="myTextArea" rows="7" cols="50">Edita el texto... Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</textarea>
<hr />
<button id="btnLeer">Leer Texto</button>
```